# Spring and Thymeleaf, how does spring know to use a template?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I've been working through some of the Spring tutorials at:

http://spring.io/guides

And i'm looking specifically at:

http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

And it's really unclear to me how the Spring model resolves using the proper .html file.  Could anyone explain this or provide links?  Is it naming convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example request from the link you provided the return value is the name of the view that will be rendered.

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "greeting";
}
```

The default view resolver for Thymeleaf will automatically append .html. See [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Thymeleaf-Spring3.html#spring-based-template-resolution).

The tutorial for Thymeleaf and Spring integration is [here.](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Thymeleaf-Spring3.html)